# Could not find tag for codec subrip in stream, codec not currently supported in container

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video to lower quality using the following comand :

> `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:a copy -map 0:5 -map 0:6 -map 0:7 -c:s copy -map 0:9 -c:v h264_nvenc -rc constqp -qp 23 -map 0:0 out.mp4`

With stream 0:9 being a subtitle. I get

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:9 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:4 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x55c6edd3a640] track 0: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x55c6edd3a640] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x55c6edd3a640] track 2: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x55c6edd3a640] Could not find tag for codec subrip in stream #3, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:4 --
```

If I change `-c:s copy` with `-c:s mov_text`, the error is gone, but then the subtitle doesn't work. Everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: MP4 only supports mov_text softsubs but player support is not universal. Use a better player, use a different output container format, or use hardsubs.

Comment: I'm converting an mkv into an mkv. I would assume they would have the same support.
If I
`ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v h264_nvenc -rc constqp -qp 20 out.mkv`
the subtitles work.

Comment: But your command and the incomplete log show MP4.

Comment: I see. The encoder of the original file: libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4. The encoder of the new file: Lavf58.20.100. Can I change this?

Comment: Why do you want to change that?

Comment: You said that mp4 doesn't support mov_text. The original obviously did. So how can I change that so that the output supports subtitles?

Comment: I don't see where I said MP4 **doesn't** support mov_text. I said MP4 **only supports** mov_text if you want softsubs. Your .mkv input appears to have SRT subs. Either output MKV, or if you need MP4 then either burn-in the subs (hardsubs), or use mov_text with a player that supports them.

Comment: Lol. I thought I was using mkv. Stupid me... Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are outputting MP4, but it only supports `mov_text` (a generic name for streaming text format [14496-17]) softsubs. However, player support is not universal.

Use a better player (VLC, mpv, Pot Player), use a different output container format (such as MKV), or use hardsubs (see [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filer).